# Strlen returns undefined behaviour with C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, strlen

```
int main ()
{
     char* tab=new char[14] ;
     cout << " lenght with sizeof: "<<sizeof(tab)<<endl;
     cout << " length with strlen: "<<strlen(tab)<<endl;
     
     system(" pause");
     return 0;
}
```

I got the output:

> length with sizeof: 4
>
> length with strlen: 30

I expect the result of `sizeof` but not what return `strlen`!

*For those who will hurry to publish that it's a duplicate question.
I want to say that it's not the opportunity at all. Because I know about compile time and run-time and many other things concerning `strlen` and `sizeof` however I cannot find explanation to this result.*

**Thank you for help in advance.**

Comment: `sizeof(tab)` gives you the size of a `char*` pointer, not the allocated spaces size, or the size of a null terminated c-string stored in there.

Comment: Your `char` array is not initialized, thus the result of `strlen` is undefined as it will count all characters until it founds a null character.

Comment: @  πάντα ῥεῖ Thanks friend. I'm agree with you but you don't understand my question, I'm asking about the result returned by strlen wich is 30 !!

Comment: So many duplicates...

Comment: @SADOK Have a look at _@geoffroy_'s comment, that explains why.

Comment: @SADOK And what's wrong with duplicates BTW?

Comment: @Deduplicator, I thought that my problem is different because I allocated espace memory usinh new char !

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ don't understand you! what a BTW duplicates ?

Comment: @SADOK Reads: _'And what's wrong with duplicates by the way?'_

Comment: Anyway, I know that my question is not like any other. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're allocating a char array but do not initialize it, `strlen()` will count from the beginning of the `tab` pointer to the first NUL character. So the result depends on the contents of your program's heap.

Comment: Should probably mention that this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: As is, this is an upvoted bad answer.

Comment: Feel free to explain what's bad about it, or provide a better answer.